# Run a simple python / abjad code in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Windows 10, Python 3.10.5

This simple code

```
import abjad
n = abjad.Note("c'4")
abjad.show(n)
```

works flawlessly when I run it from the command line using `py test.py`. It automatically launches my pdf viewer showing this:
[image: python output]

But when I try to run it from Visual studio code it doesn't "work": it doesn't launch the pdf viewer.

This is what Visual studio code prints in the terminal:

```
PS G:\My Drive\repos\ttd> & "g:/My Drive/repos/ttd/ttdvenv/Scripts/Activate.ps1"

(ttdvenv) PS G:\My Drive\repos\ttd>  & 'g:\My Drive\repos\ttd\ttdvenv\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Gianmaria\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.8.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '62264' '--' 'g:\My Drive\repos\ttd\test.py'

(ttdvenv) PS G:\My Drive\repos\ttd>
```

Any suggestion what can be the issue?
Thank you!

Comment: did you go through the documentation of the [abjad](https://abjad.github.io/)?

Comment: Are you able to use any other library functionality properly from Visual Studio Code? For example, can you use `abjad` to create the PDF, and then locate the file and open it manually?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

I'm able to see the pdf file generated by python/abjad and to open it manually.
The pdf file is correctly generated both when I run the program from the command line and from Visual Studio Code.

When it's run from Visual Studio Code, though, the pdf viewer doesn't open automatically.